# Enjin/DonationCraft: /give with DataTag not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'm trying to offer a Tool with Enchantments in a rank using the following command:

```
/Minecraft:give {uuid} minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:0.1,Operation:1,UUIDLeast:161132,UUIDMost:640840,Slot:"mainhand"}],RepairCost:60,ench:[{id:32,lvl:6},{id:34,lvl:4},{id:35,lvl:3}],display:{Name:"Tool Name",Lore:["Lore Name"]}}
```

Running this command in console, works great.
But when running through Enjin/DonationCraft (buying rank), I'm having the following error:

```
Data tag parsing failed: Expected ':' but got '<EOF>' at: ...and"}],RepairCost:60,ench:[{id:32,l<--[HERE]
```

Does Enjin require any special syntax? It only seems to fail when having `AttributeModifiers`.

Comment: i literally have no idea about Enjin or Donationcraft, but the first thing that comes to mind is a possible character limit on the commands you can issue? Seeing as the Error you're getting is inside the enchantment (and not the Modifiers) and it's a EOF error!

Comment: Try a part of this command. The fact that's it's so incredibly long shows that you haven't tried anything to fix it yourself. With such a long command, there are hundreds of different possible causes, so nobody can help you.

Comment: @Fabian Where did you get that idea? I said it only fails with the `AttributeModifiers`. The whole command works without it.

Comment: Does it fail with only `AttributeModifiers`? In general, always give the minimum need setup to reproduce the error. And you can also reduce that tag further, for example by not restricting it to a hand.

Comment: Apparently @Plagiatus was right, and it's a character limit at 255. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

DonationCraft limits commands at 255 characters. It doesn't show up on any documentation at all, but I did a lot of tests and that was the conclusion.

With a command with less than 255 characters, everything works fine, enchantments and attribute modifiers.